# Entity Framevork code first обновление записи в таблице со связью один ко многим

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Помогите разобраться в проблеме.

Пытаюсь реализовать с помощью entity framework code first обновление записи в таблице которая связана еще с одной таблицей связью многие к одному.

Вот модели данных

```
public class Defect
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string index { get; set; }
    public string specification { get; set; }
    public int amountOfBalls { get; set; }

    public virtual DefectCategory defectCategory { get; set; }
}


public class DefectCategory
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string index { get; set; }
    public string specification { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Defect> defects { get; set; }
}
```

Вот метод контроллера GET

```
    public ActionResult DefectEdit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Defect defect = db.Defects.Find(id);
        if (defect == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.defectCategory_id = new SelectList(db.DefectCategories, "id", "specification", defect.defectCategory.id);
        return View(defect);
    }
```

Вот метод контроллера POST

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DefectEdit(Defect defect, int defectCategory_id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            defect.defectCategory = db.DefectCategories.Find(defectCategory_id);
            db.Entry(defect).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ListDefects");
        }
        return View(defect);
    }
```

Вот представление

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <h4>Відредагувати існуючий дефект</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.index, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.index, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.index, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.defectCategory, "defectCategory_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("defectCategory_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.defectCategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.specification, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.specification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.specification, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.amountOfBalls, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.amountOfBalls, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.amountOfBalls, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Зберегти" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Проблема в том что в базе данных обновляються все измененные поля кроме defectCategory_id которое сгенерировано фреймворком и доступа к нему напрямую у меня я так понимаю нет(или есть?) одним словом помогите разобраться как правильно в контроллере и представлении реализовать связь один ко многим

Comment: зачем в методе "POST" параметр "defectCategory_id" разве "defect" не содержит уже измененное значение категории дефекта?

Comment: нет, у меня defect.defectCategory приходит null. У меня воопще впечатление что я что то глобально делаю не так...

Comment: Добавте примеры данных для обоих объектов(Defect и DefectCategory) попробую посмотреть у себя

Comment: DefectCategory
первая: index - A, specification - дефекти паперу
вторая: index - В, specification - дефекти тексту
Defect
index - a1, defectCategory - дефекти паперу(по факту в таблице поле defectCategory_id с айдишником выбраной категории), specification - тест,  amountOfBalls - 10

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите должно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Defect
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfBalls { get; set; }

    //Предпочитаю создавать поля сам
    public int DefectCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefectCategoryId")] // указываю какое поле будет использоваться для связи
    public virtual DefectCategory DefectCategory { get; set; }
}

public class DefectCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Defect> Defects { get; set; }
}
```

методы Get и Post остались прежними. Ниже код контроллера целиком:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public List<DefectCategory> DefectCategories = new List<DefectCategory>()
    {
        new DefectCategory(){Id = 1,Index="A", Specification = "дефекти паперу"},
        new DefectCategory(){Id = 2, Index="B", Specification="дефекти тексту"}
    };

    public List<Defect> Defects = new List<Defect>
    {
        new Defect(){Id=1, Index="A1", Specification="тест", AmountOfBalls = 10, DefectCategoryId = 1}
    };


    public ActionResult ListDefects()
    {
        return View(Defects);
    }

    public ActionResult DefectEdit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var defect = Defects.Find(x=>x.Id==id);
        if (defect == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.DefectCategories = new SelectList(DefectCategories, "id", "specification");
        return View(defect);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DefectEdit(Defect defect)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //defect.defectCategory = db.DefectCategories.Find(defectCategory_id);
            return RedirectToAction("ListDefects");
        }
        return View(defect);
    }
```

представление для редактирования

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.Defect

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DefectEdit";
}

<h2>DefectEdit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Defect</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Index, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Index, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Index, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Specification, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Specification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Specification, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountOfBalls, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountOfBalls, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountOfBalls, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DefectCategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DefectCategoryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.DefectCategories, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefectCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

если поставить точку останова в методе пост, то Мы увидим что defect.DefectCategoryId содержит то значение ключа которое Мы выбрали

Comment: все равно defect.defectCategory приходит null, А перемнная которая приходить в мето пост вместе с обьектом defect стала называться defectCategory.

Comment: UPD результат тот же, кроме того в текущей реализации мне ModelState.IsValid возвращает в методе POST false.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое добрый человек. Особенно за это public int DefectCategoryId { get; set; } и [ForeignKey("DefectCategoryId")]. Пошел переделывать свои модели данных.

Comment: Для освоения могу посоветовать почитать вот [это](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/index.php), сам начинал осваивать с этого